# String of ImportError messages when I try to import requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to run a Python program but encounter a series of errors when I import the requests module (version 2.21.0).

I have tried uninstalling requests and re-installing but this does not solve the problem.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall requests
sudo pip3 install requests
```

Code I am running (in the interactive shell):

```
import re
import requests
```

I expect the package to simply load, however I am getting the following string of errors:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/Users/willward/Desktop/email.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests.exceptions
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPError' from 'urllib3.exceptions' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py)
```

I have also tried uninstalling urllib3 and reinstalling it and I get the following errors:

```
Python 3.7.1 (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 03:13:28) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .exceptions import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/Users/willward/Desktop/email.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests.exceptions
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py", line 9, in <module>
    from urllib3.exceptions import HTTPError as BaseHTTPError
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPError' from 'urllib3.exceptions' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/exceptions.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are having issue with urllib3. Try to uninstall urllib3 and reinstall it maybe?

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this and get same issue (see updated post)